# The toc=idx option of the KOMA-Script doesn't work with the package imakeidx

Tags: koma-script, indexing, imakeidx

If one use one of this class options: `toc=idx`, `toc=index`, `index=toc`, `index=totoc` or `index=notnumbered` of one of the `KOMA-Script` classes and the package `imakeidx` together, than the *Index* entry (IE) doesn't appear in the table of contents (ToC). See the code:

IE doesn't appear in the ToC for all five `KOMA-Script` options:

```
\documentclass[toc=idx]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[toc=index]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[index=toc]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[index=toc]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[index=totoc]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[index=notnumbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents
  \section{Test}
    Das Zweistrom-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerk (ZTL)\index{ZTL}~\ldots

  \printindex

\end{document}
```

It only appears, if one use the optional argument `intoc` of the `makeindex` command:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc]

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{Test}
    Das Zweistrom-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerk (ZTL)\index{ZTL}~\ldots

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Should it work like this?

For prove same example with `makeidx` package (again for all five `KOMA-Script` class options):

```
\documentclass[toc=idx]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[toc=index]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[index=toc]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[index=toc]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[index=totoc]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[index=notnumbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{Test}
    Das Zweistrom-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerk (ZTL)\index{ZTL}~\ldots

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imakeindx` redefines `theindex` environment for typesetting the indices. Then the index is under control of this package and you have to use its option `intoc` to get a TOC entry of the index as in your second example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc]

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{Test}
    Das Zweistrom-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerk (ZTL)\index{ZTL}~\ldots

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If you want to use `theindex` environment provided by the KOMA-Script-class, set option `original` for package `imakeidx`. Then you can use a KOMA-Script option to get the desired TOC entry.

```
\documentclass[index=totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[texindy,original]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{Test}
    Das Zweistrom-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerk (ZTL)\index{ZTL}~\ldots

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]